# Dead light out side

Tags: electrical, lighting

I was installing a light bulb outside of the house. Accidentally I caused a short between positive and negative. Now I cannot get power to the outlet. I did check all switches of the fuse box, but none were tripped. I reset all of them and also the main switch. But no power to that point. All other circuits are working fine. How can I find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your light might be fed by a GFCI outlet.  Check all the outlets outside the house and in the garage to see if they need to be reset.

Comment: If you really shorted the connections, you may have caused the wire or fixture to melt somewhere. That would cause an open circuit (no power). When you say all other circuits are working fine, are you saying that all that was on this circuit breaker was the one outside light?  Or are you saying that all the other fixtures on this circuit work?

Answer (score 1):

I am very surprised to hear that you shorted out the connection in the bulb.  That It is rather difficult to do that in a fixture which is properly designed (and not broken, obviously).  I suspect your fixture is broken.  (and the bulb isn't - check the old bulb).

But here's a thought.  You went out to change the bulb because it was not lighting, yes?   Maybe it wasn't lighting because the fixture was already broken.  Did you see sparks or have some other reason to believe you shorted the fixture?  If so, it is probably in the bulb socket area.  Or have you seen no evidence of power at all? - then the problem could be anywhere, such as at the base of the fixture, the wiring to your home, or the wiring in your home.